# Is it possible to create interface for user to reset auto-number field?

Tags: auto-number

I know that system administrator can reset auto number according to [How do I reset/restart an auto number field?](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005195&language=en_US).But is it allow to be resetted by user through visualforce?Is it possible to develop it?

Comment: It could be done via the metadata api. Look at JSForce or using Ajax to call the metadata API

Comment: I will try right away.

Comment: @Eric I check here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm , autonumber is not supported.am i reading the correct article?

Comment: It would seem that you are correct and it is one of those things that you cannot I guess.Sorry about getting your hopes up.

Comment: but @Eric I bump to jsforce which is really cool. https://jsforce.github.io/document/ . =)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to Answer this although it is not as I expected, so it will help other people to refer.

Auto Number cannot be reset through metadata api. Please refer here :[Unsupported Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm)

> Standard fields that aren’t customizable, such as autonumber fields or
>   system fields

The best way is to let the user know that they always can contact their System Admin to reset it for them.